# Bind ng-model name to chosen

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, angularjs-directive

I can't figure out why I'm not able to bind an object to ng-model in choosen directive

Heres my HTMl content code:

```
 <select class="form-control" required
                        multiple
                        ng-model="selectedItems"
                        ng-options="r.id as r.name for r in availableItems"
                        chosen>
                </select>
```

The JSON:

```
$scope.selectedItems= [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Selected 1",
            "description": "Nulla adi architecto et",

        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Selected 2",
            "description": "test",

        }
    ]

$scope.availableItems= [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Available 1",
            "description": "Nulla adi architecto et",

        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Available 2",
            "description": "test",

        }
    ]
```

However I'm able to display the available items in the select drop down but my requirement:
To display the selected items by default in the input box of choosen.

Reference:[Localytics-Angular Choosen](https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen)

Comment: Could you add a jsfiddle of the problem? I think that would help visualize the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular will automatically select the items by comparing them with the value of `ng-model`. In your case, the selected item is `r.id`, which is a primitive, so the equality will be based on comparing `r.id`s:

```
$scope.selectedItems = [1, 2];
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QczOQaYvf243Ga45Eux1?p=preview)

Comment: Well Explained @New Dev